What is the concept and logic for creating the Login,Authenticating and Routing components for Login in React
I created a Routing (v6), a loginAuthentication, and LoginPage component,
but unable to understand, what logic should be followed with LoginAuthentication and Loginpage,
Currently I'm using on frontend authentication as, when the login button is pressed in the LoginPage Component, the loginAuthentication Component's authenticated must become true and move me to /home,
but how do I achieve it? It's kinda confusing
here is what I did,
LoginAuthentication.js

import { useLocation, useNavigation, Navigate, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom'
import TestLogin from './TestLogin'

export default function TestLoginAuth() {
    // let location=useLocation();
    // let navigate=useNavigation()
    let [authentication, setAuthentication] = useState(false)
    // console.log(authentication,navigate,location)
    console.log(authentication, '<--Authentication')
    // if(authentication===undefined) {return false};

    const updateAuthentication = () => {
        setAuthentication(true);
    };

    return (<>
        {authentication ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to='loginpage' replace />}
        <TestLogin updateAuthentication={updateAuthentication} />
    </>)
}


Login.js

import { useRef, useState } from 'react';
import {useLocation,useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom'
import { LoginAuth } from './TestAuth';

export default function TestLogin({updateAuthentication}){

    let [login,setLogin]=useState(false)

    // let history=useHistory();
    let location= useLocation();
    const navigate=useNavigate()
    let username=useRef('')
    let password=useRef('');

    const handleLogin = () => {
        // Perform login logic
        // Assuming authentication is successful
        updateAuthentication();
        navigate('/testhome', { replace: true });
    };

    return(
        <>
            <main>
                <input type='text' ref={username}/>
                <input type='password' ref={password}/>

                {/* <button >Login</button> */}
                <button onClick={handleLogin}>Submit</button>
            </main>
        </>
    )

}

MyRoutes.js
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<TestLoginAuth />} />
  <Route path="testhome" element={<TestHome />} />
  <Route path="demotest" element={<TestParent />} />
  <Route path="demoitem" element={<TestItems />} />
  <Route path="loginpage" element={<TestLogin />} />
</Routes>

and if I want to use the useLocation,useNavigation then how will it be?
